# How to do Real time auto extraction of information into excel from outlook emails with attachments?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, automation, software-rec, list

How does one extract into an excel spreadsheet a ordered list in real time for emails containing attachments the file name and type, the date, and email subject?

Is there some kind of software that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might need VBA and outlook rules to help you auto export the Attachment Information of Incoming Outlook Emails to an Excel Workbook. Please reference: https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-export-attachment-information-incoming-outlook-emails-excel-workbook/.

Comment: How does one do it on a Mac?

Comment: do you have pointers on a mac?

Comment: As I know, VBA is not supported in Outlook for Mac. I tried searches but have not found existing AppleScript related to this issue yet.

Comment: Do you suggest stackoverflowing a translation of their code into apple script or Automator?

Comment: Considering the differences between different programming languages, not quite sure if this is available. Sorry about that.